# Slow GitLab backup process. Any way to speed up?

Tags: gitlab, backup

I have the following setup:

- GitLab CE (16.9) on VirtualBox VM (4vCPUs, 10GB RAM, 1.5TB disk space), OS Ubuntu 20.04
- Host machine running Ubuntu 22.04
- Mounted folder from host to VM using vboxfs where the backups are stored
- VM hosted on NVME disk
- mounted folder for backups on HDD
- gitlab backup is performed without any parameters (just gitlab-backup create)

The problem:
I have setup cron jobs for backing up the GitLab, which works as it should, but it takes quite some time.
It takes around 10 hours to complete the process.
Most of this (~8hours) is the copying of the repositories directory (~360GB) (total backup size ~530GB)

Does this seem normal?
My though is that it's not, copying 400GBs shouldn't take that much time...
If I'm correct and it's indeed slow, what should I do to speed up the process?

Thanks in advance!